# Bounds for Discrete Poisson Kernel of a Square

Tags: inequalities, random-walks, harmonic-functions, difference-equations

I am having difficulty in proving the lower bound of the discrete Poisson kernel of a square denoted as $H$ described below. It is stated in [Gregory F. Lawler's Randomm Walk and the Heat Equation](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~lawler/reu.pdf) as Equations (1.26)-(1.28) but not proved. I think it relates to the Harnack inequality. Hints or answer would be greatly appreciated.

---

For natural number $N$ let $\beta_j$, $j\in\{1,2,\cdots,N-1\}$, such that
$$\cosh\Big(\frac{\beta_j\pi}{N}\Big)+\cos\Big(\frac{j\pi}{N}\Big)=2.$$
Define 
$A = \big\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbf N^2: \frac{N}4\le x_j\le\frac34N, j\in\{1,2\}\big\}$, and
$$H(y,x):= \frac{2}{N-1}\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\frac1{\sinh(\beta_j\pi)}\sin\Big(\frac{j\pi y}{N}\Big)\sinh\Big(\frac{\beta_j\pi x_1}{N}\Big)\sin\Big(\frac{j\pi x_2}{N}\Big)$$
for $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y\in\{1,2,\cdots,N-1\}$.
How do I show that there exists positive constants $c$ and $c_1$ such that
$$\frac1{cN}\sin\Big(\frac{\pi y}{N}\Big)\le H(y,x)\le \frac{c}{N}\sin\Big(\frac{\pi y}{N}\Big) \tag1$$
and
$$|H(y,x)-H(y,\tilde x)|\le c_1\frac{|x-\tilde x|}{N}H(y,x) \tag2,$$
$\forall x,\tilde x\in A.$

---

I can show that $\beta_j>\epsilon j$ for some positive $\epsilon$ and prove the right inequality in Equation (1) but am having trouble for the rest of the inequalities.